# I was making a Program, of selection sorting using array int Turbo C++

Tags: c++, sorting, selection

The Output will be having four column for serial number, the user input, ascending order and descending order. I am doing it in Turbo C++ but after compiling it is giving 12 errors.
- Declaration terminated incorrectly
- Declaration syntax error
- Variable 'i' and 'j' is initialized more than once
- Declaration terminated incorrectly

The Program is:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
clrscr();
int a[10][3];    
cout<<"Enter Number of elements: \n";
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
cin>>a[i][0];
a[i][1]=a[i][0];
a[i][2]=a[i][0];
}
for(int j=9;j>0;j--)
{
for(i=0;i<j;i++)
{
int t;
t=a[i+1][1];
a[i+1][1]=a[i][1];
a[i][1]=t;
}
}
return 0;
};
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
a[i][1];
}
for( j=9;j>0;j--)
{
for(i=0;i<j;i++)
{
if(a[i][2]<a[i+1][2])
{
int t;
t=a[i+1][2];
a[i+1][2]=a[i][2];
a[i][2]=a[i][2];
a[i][2]=t;
}
}
}
cout<<"|\tSr.No\t|\tUser Input\t|\tA.O\t|\tD.O\t|";
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
cout<<" "<<i+1<<"\t\t|\t\t"<<b[i][0]<<"\t\t|\t\t"b[i][2]<<"\t\t|\t\t"<<b[i][1]<<endl;
}
getch();
```

Comment: I don't see a question ...

Comment: Can anyone please fix the errors..

Comment: You declare i and j in one for and then you don't do that again. This might be the error. If you declare it in the fors, the variable does not exist outside the for, so you need to declare it again in every new for.

Comment: @Aziuth: Can u please elaborate

Comment: That said, you should use indentation for your code. Also, you shouldn't use arrays in C++, go with vectors instead. Arrays are prone to errors. And you shouldn't use "magic numbers", like your 9s and 10s that come from nowhere - go with something like the size()-method of vectors.

Comment: You use "for(int j=9;j>0;j--)", but later you go with "for( j=9;j>0;j--)". In that second for, the compiler has no idea what j could be. j does exist only in the first for, after that, the system completely forgets it. You need to declare j also in the second for. Same with i. Also, try to write actual sentences, "Can u" is lazy.

Comment: Actually i am just a beginner..

Comment: @Aziuth: If u r not busy enough, can u please make me a program for what i want... please

Comment: I gave you the answer - declare the variables in your fors, always "for(int i = " instead of "for(i =". Stack Overflow is not meant to do your homework.

Comment: oh now u said it,, okay i understand... not declaring the variables again and again.. thankyou

Comment: To clarify it to you, so you have a better understanding of it all: Memory is precious. Therefore, a compiler wants to avoid that the program is storing unnecessary data. One thing it does to accomplish this is to make the program to recycle storage. A variable has a time frame in which it "lives". This is the part of the code in which it was declared. If you declare something within { }-brackets, it does not live outside of those - even in a while, after each iteration, stuff that is declared within the brackets dies. A condition or the triple of a FOR are thought to be within the brackets.

Comment: The same holds for a function or a method. The noteworthy exception are pointers, but I won't elaborate since this was enough for now.